# lxml validates xml when written to file, and read back but does not validate DOM tree from which file is generated

Tags: python, xml, validation, lxml

I'm using lxml to generate xml and validate it. I have found that when I try to use an XSD validator to validate the DOM tree, the validator complains that it does not recognise the root element; by contrast when that tree is converted to text, written to a file, and read back and parsed to a DOM tree, the new DOM tree's root element is recognised. Hopefully the below will illustrate what I mean.

My question is: why does this happen? Is there a way to get the original DOM tree to validate other than rendering to a string, and reparsing?

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import io
>>> validator = etree.XMLSchema(etree.parse(io.open('mainapp/xsd/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v2-6.xsd')))
>>> c = CompanyUK.objects.all()[5]
>>> cotree = xml.Company.generate_company_incorporation_tree(c)
>>> cotree
<Element CompanyIncorporation at 0x38f2750>
>>> validator.assertValid(cotree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element 'CompanyIncorporation': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
>>> cott = etree.ElementTree(cotree)
>>> validator.assertValid(cott)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element 'CompanyIncorporation': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
>>> xmlfile = open("xmlfile", "w")
>>> xmlfile.write(etree.tostring(cott))
>>> xmlfile.flush()
>>> xmlfile.close()
>>> xmlfile = open("xmlfile", "r")
>>> ptree = etree.parse(xmlfile)
>>> validator.assertValid(ptree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}Country': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'EW' is not an element of the set {'GB-ENG', 'GB-WLS', 'GB-SCT', 'GB-NIR', 'GBR', 'UNDEF'}., line 1
>>> etree.tostring(ptree) == etree.tostring(cott)
True
>>> validator.assertValid(etree.parse(io.StringIO(etree.tounicode(ptree))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}Country': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'EW' is not an element of the set {'GB-ENG', 'GB-WLS', '
GB-SCT', 'GB-NIR', 'GBR', 'UNDEF'}., line 1
>>> validator.assertValid(etree.parse(io.StringIO(etree.tounicode(cot))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cot' is not defined
>>> validator.assertValid(etree.parse(io.StringIO(etree.tounicode(cott))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}Country': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'EW' is not an element of the set {'GB-ENG', 'GB-WLS', '
GB-SCT', 'GB-NIR', 'GBR', 'UNDEF'}., line 1
>>> validator.assertValid(etree.parse(io.BytesIO(etree.tostring(cott))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}Country': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'EW' is not an element of the set {'GB-ENG', 'GB-WLS', '
GB-SCT', 'GB-NIR', 'GBR', 'UNDEF'}., line 1
>>>
```

As you can see above, validation gets further with the version parsed from disk, even though they render to the same string (and likewise, validation gets beyond the root element after a roundtrip to string, and re-parsed to a DOM tree). So, what might be causing this?

Comment: What is the type of the return value of CompanyUK.objects.all()[5]?

Comment: @DerekLitz : CompanyUK - it's a django model.